# Issue to run a python executable code on ROS2

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble, msg-subscriber

I have successfully tested my python deep learning code (Not a ROS node) for Pointcloud object detection using anaconda. In the prediction code, I can run `exec(open('test.py').read())` for object detection.

I created a ROS2 python subscriber for deep learning 3D object detection. I still use `exec(open('test.py').read())` in the ROS2 node. The `test.py` is existed in the directories below:

```
/home/user/DL_ws/install/object_detection/lib/python3.10/site-packages/object_detection
/home/user/DL_ws/install/object_detection/lib/python3.10/site-packages/object_detection/ML
/home/user/DL_ws/src/object_detection/object_detection/ML
```

After running `ros2 run object_detection listener`, I get this error

```
  File "/home/user/DL_ws/install/object_detection/lib/python3.10/site-packages/object_detection/pc_subscriber.py", line 145, in callback
    exec(open('test.py').read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.py'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks,

Abbas

Comment: This comment may seem unsophisticated, but when these types of issues pop up for me I frequently test by explictly including entire file path to see if that helps. If it does then I decide if getting to true cause of error is worth it, or if I roll with the hard coded path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I do not get the error now, but the executable python code is not functional. Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: You should open a anew question and include additional things like log files and the results of the debug steps you've gone through.